# Trying to get auth on spotify ios SDK

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth-2.0, spotify

How do I receive an access token with the SDK? So far I have managed to set up a simple login and play a specific song in swift, however, I am not quite sure how access tokens work and how I get a hold of the current one?
Sorry if this question is a bit vague, I'm just pretty confused. This is one of my first projects with iOS.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The access token lives on the [`SPTAppRemoteConnectionParams`](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/html/Classes/SPTAppRemoteConnectionParams.html). A good reference to see how to access, configure, and use it would be the [demo projects in the Spotify iOS SDK](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/tree/d341632c4809eedf9e9fff2069766bd9f903e4f8/DemoProjects). When you get the access token it would be good to save it somewhere to use throughout the app once authentication has finished.